# Convert SAS syntax for mixed models for repeated measures in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, sas, lme4-nlme

I want to attain a p-value in R using `lme4` or `nlme` which has been obtained from mixed models (`procmixed`) for repeated measures in SAS. The syntax for the model in SAS is the following:

```
PROCMIXED DATA= datab(where= (visnum GT 0)) CLMETHOD=REML NOBOUND COVTEST;
            CLASS treatment site id visnum sitec;
            MODEL y_chng = treatment week treatment*week y_base /  
                    SOLUTION RESIDUAL INFLUENCE(EFFECT=id ITER=5) VCIRY OUTPM= RES COVB;
            RANDOM intercept / SUBJECT=sitec TYPE=vc;
            RANDOM intercept / SUBJECT=id(sitec) TYPE=UN;
            ESTIMATE 'Y versus X at 24 weeks versus 12 weeks' treatment*week 12-12;
            CONTRAST 'Total treatment effect'treatment  1-1, treatment*week 12-12;
RUN;
```

The data comes from an experiment between two treatment groups (`treatment`) where participants (`id`) from different sites (`sitec`) have been measured on a continuous outcome (`y`) in three time points (`week`) namely baseline, 12 weeks and 24 weeks. The `y_chng` is the adjusted `y` and the baseline value `y_base` is included as a covariate in the model.

In R I created a variable `y_base` by repeating the baseline `y` value as many times as the measurements for each individual. Thus, for `y_chng` I have set the difference `y - y_base`.

I tried `lme4` with `lmerTest` and `lsmeans` to get the same p value with no success. In my opinion the model formula in `lme4` would be something like

```
y_chng ~ treatment + week + treatment*week + y_base + (1|sitec/id)
```

@Jeremy Miles : This is the suntax that I have been provided. Since I want to get exactly the same p-value in R I assume that the `TYPE=vc` or `TYPE=UN` in SAS syntax matters.

Comment: Although this asks for code, it isn't really a programming question. There may be enough statistical content here for this to be on topic.

Comment: As a matter of coding hygene, you should put spaces between the commands, especially if you want others to be able to read your code. -1

Comment: It's a while since I've used SAS, but are type=VC and type=UN necessary here?

Comment: First, worry about the parameter estimates - are these the same across programs?

Comment: most likely issue (although not reproducible) is a difference in default contrasts.  Have you tried `options(contrasts=c("contr.SAS","contr.poly"))` and/or `options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))` ... ?